# OperationError: Failed to execute 'createOffer' on 'RTCPeerConnection when using CEFSharp

Tags: webrtc, chromium, cefsharp

I have been getting the error "OperationError: Failed to execute 'createOffer' on 'RTCPeerConnection" whenever I open Microsoft Teams on CEFSharp browser and attempt to start/join a meeting with audio and video. The error comes up when i try to mute or unmute. This error does not come up in Google chrome.

To reproduce error:

1. start an instance of CEFSharp browser and navigate to "https://teams.com"
2. Start or join a meeting with vieo and audio.
3. Attempt to mute audio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpo1m.png)

Comment: What version are you using? Have you enabled WebRTC? It's not enabled by default.

Comment: version is v85.3.130. Yes I enabled it. I added this " settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream");". The problem is that there is video during the meeting but no audio. Nobody can hear me. I am thinking a codec issue maybe H.264 which is proprietary. Teams meetings depend on them https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts

Comment: H264 is technically a video codec, not an audio codec. H264 is often paired with AAC audio, both are proprietary and not supported by default due to licensing restrictions.

Comment: Thanks amaitland for your swift reply. I will go back and take a hard look at the logs.